# Why my regex does not find substring in input data

Tags: java, regex

This is my code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":\\s(.+)\\s[cfs]");
Matcher m1 = p.matcher("Seat 9: -FACERAPE- folded before Flop");
String name = null;
while(m1.find()){
    name = m1.group(1);
}
System.out.println(name);
```

I tried this regex pattern [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) and it works there but in my IDE it does not work. I use Eclipse with jdk 1.6. Also my regex works with these examples: Seat 7: Goldball31 folded before Flop, Seat 4: <*{{{>< collected (3.09). As you see problem is in hyphen but I did not get what a problem.
Oh sorry forget that it prints "null"

Comment: Your code prints `-FACERAPE-`. Now explain what is wrong with that.

Comment: My code prints "null" and generate nullpointerexception

Comment: Well why don't you demonstrate the code that does that. This code prints `-FACERAPE-`.

Comment: @user1346834: No, it doesn't. The quoted code, when copied and pasted into a class, shows the text as Marko indicated.

Comment: @Mat: That's my point, so am I, whereas the OP says it throws an NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong, but your regular expression should be:

```
:\\s(.+?)\\s[cfs]
```

or

```
:\\s(\\S+)\\s[cfs]
```

Comment: hm tried to write java code in notepad and it works. Nickname could contain several whitespaces;) .Thanks for a help, I should reinstall my Eclipse. Close this theme.

Comment: If Nick can contain whitespace then your regular expression will fail for any nick, which contains c, f or s at the beginning of a word of the nick.

Comment: I understand that but dont know how to use full word with OR: showed OR folded OR collected. Maybe you help me?

Comment: '(.*?) (showed|folded|collected) '

Comment: ... and that one fails for an nick containing `showed|folded|collected` :)